# PHP, SQL query save '0' in float database when entered String from the php form

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

The website should abort the query when the datatype is wrong. But what I got is, if I put string value to a float datatype, it save as '0'.

```
<?php  
 require('db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['prodName']) and isset($_POST['prodPrice']) and isset($_POST['prodQuantity'])){

// Assigning POST values to variables.
$name = $_POST['prodName'];
$price = $_POST['prodPrice'];
$quantity = $_POST['prodQuantity'];

// CHECK FOR THE RECORD FROM TABLE
$query = "INSERT INTO product (name, price, quantity) VALUES ('$name','$price','$quantity')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

if ($query){

//echo "Login Credentials verified";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Product Added');
    window.location.href='menu.php';
</script>";
}
else{
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Invalid Login Credentials');
    window.location.href='login.php';
</script>";
//echo "Invalid Login Credentials";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put the $result instead of $query in the if condition. As for the '0' query result, if i'm not wrong, it means false, meaning the datas you try to be inserted, can't be saved because of an error (Most likely the data types). And you should validate the $_POST values first before inserting it.

For Example:

```
if (is_float($_POST['prodName']) === false || is_float($_POST['prodPrice']) === false 
|| is_float($_POST['prodQuantity']) === false) 
&& echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Invalid Login Credentials');
window.location.href='login.php'; </script>";
```

With validation, you would prevent undesired values entering your databse and minimize the risk of compromising your whole web application.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize my mistakes